# Generate patterns from a given string in java

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching

Given a string  `str = ab12`. 
I'm trying to generate patterns as below

`xbx2  ax1x  abxx  xx12`

Here's one more example to make it a bit clear :
Original String `182d3c`
Required pattern :
`18xdxc 182x3x 18xx3c 182dxx 18xxxx` See that 18 is constant and other two varying
`x82dxc 1x2d3x xx2d3c 182dxx xx2dxx` See now 2d is constant others are varying

so on and on...

> Note that number of `x` in any pattern must be even.

I tried using regex but to no avail. 
then i thought may be binary pattern generation algo will help (it seems somewhat like binary pattern with `x`), but still i'm not there. :(

If you need more info please comment, I'll be happy to share.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks!

Comment: So at once, only two letters/numbers will be visible?

Comment: Why the c# tag if you Need a solution for Java as your title mentioned?

Comment: What is the max length of the input string? And do you generate all the patterns (as strings) and use it later or something...I mean...what is the purpose of it (if that matters)?

Comment: No, i need exact same patterns as shown above. `x` means x, its not a placeholder or variable. See patterns some times its two letters/numbers visible some times its four.  but the number of `x` are even in all cases.

Comment: @Jens C# and java are like sisten langs.. if i get a solution in C# i can convert in java. End of the day logic matters. Cheers!

Comment: @vish4071 `MAX length is 12`. Yes i'll generate the patterns and keep it in `ArrayList` and use it later on.

Comment: @Mrmj "End of the day logic matters". 

No, the use of tags is for others to find questions that relate to their specific problems. If someone has a problem with his C# code he might search by the `C#` tag. But if he stumbles across this question which doesn't relate to C#, it won't help him much.

The same reason applies to the `javascript` tag which is also not applicable at all here because `Javascript != Java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12 characters is a safe limit.

You can use bit-mask...Iterate through `0 to 2^l - 1`, (where l = length of string) and check in the bit representation of `i`, if the number of set bits is even. If it is, mark the position of set bits as `x's` and keep the rest of the string.

This algorithm has complexity `O(l * 2^l)`, which is fine as `max(l) = 12`. So, number of operations will be of the order `2.4e4`, which is easily achievable in well under 1s.

EDIT:  As requested, sample code in Java

EDIT2: Replaced previous code with new working code :)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class xes{
    public static String convert(int n, int l){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        int g = 0;
        while(n>0){
            int c = n%2;
            if(c==0)
                s.append("0");
            else{
                s.append("1");
                g++;
            }
            n/=2;
        }
        while(s.length()<l)
            s.append("0");
        if(g%2 == 0)
            return ("" + s.reverse());
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getAllPatterns(String s){
        int l = s.length();
        int p = (1<<l) - 1;            //because you don't want all x's, so -1. 1<<l is same as power(2,l)
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=1;i<p;i++){        //i started from i=1 since you don't want all characters visible in any string in arraylist...if you want, stat it with 0
            String z = convert(i,l);
            if(z.equals("-1"))
                continue;
            StringBuilder g = new StringBuilder(s);
            for(int j=0; j < z.length(); j++){
                if(z.charAt(j)=='1')
                    g.setCharAt(j,'x');
            }
            System.out.println(g);
            arr.add("" + g);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> patterns = getAllPatterns("1823");
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
18xx
1x2x
1xx3
x82x
x8x3
xx23
```

For another input, `1823ab`, I'm getting all 30 possible (6C2 + 6C4) strings as output:

```
1823xx
182xax
182xxb
18x3ax
18x3xb
18xxab
18xxxx
1x23ax
1x23xb
1x2xab
1x2xxx
1xx3ab
1xx3xx
1xxxax
1xxxxb
x823ax
x823xb
x82xab
x82xxx
x8x3ab
x8x3xx
x8xxax
x8xxxb
xx23ab
xx23xx
xx2xax
xx2xxb
xxx3ax
xxx3xb
xxxxab
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but could you please elaborate a bit more. I'm not able to co relate it.

Comment: @Mrmj, I've updated the answer...if you still have queries...feel free.

Comment: while this solution does gets us closer to solution, the logic still fails for `1x2x` and `18xx` case.  Since `c=n%2 and  n/=2` logic excludes many cases.  Like: I ran your code, it gives `xx23,x8x3,xx23` for `1823` , but the output should've been `xx23,x8x3,1x2x,18xx`.  Any way, i'll try to improve this code and if u also have some spare time please look into it. Any way thanks again.

Comment: No...it does not...Think about  it...the logic includes all possible bit representations of length `l`...so it is not possible that it leaves any case...Try and run the program.. (Though I have not tested it (I typed it here directly), it might give some compilation errors...look for that)

Comment: Please read my last comment fully. I already ran it and gave you the results.

Comment: @Mrmj, changed the code...added only 2 significant lines...`while(s.length()<l)
            s.append("0");`

Comment: Getting close :) I ran the code, now it gives `18xx 1x3x 1xx3` for `1823`. 
Notice that now it give only those patterns which were missing in previous one.  So i think we've to combine both approaches.

Comment: I've written the output that I'm getting for this code...and the output now includes all 6 possible patterns this time :)

Comment: See the green tick up there ;)
Thank you very much vish :)

Comment: This algo freezes when i increase the number of chars to 24.
Any suggestions to make it work for 24 chars?

Comment: @Mrmj, the output for your problem *will* include 2^(n-1) output strings, where `n = length of input string`. So, in any case, any algorithm will be exponential complex.

Comment: As far as working is concerned, I run this algo on this string: `qwertyuiopasdf1234567890` and got the correct result in `0m55.641s`.